# Having problems adding markers into Google Maps clusterer

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

I have problem adding markers into marker Clusterer of Google Maps. Firebug returns error:

> Error: Invalid value for property : [object Object]' when calling
>   method: [nsIDOMEventListener::handleEvent]

Markers are created with mix of JavaScript and PHP:

```
// loop starts here.......

    var randLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng( <?php echo $lat; ?>, <?php echo $lon; ?> );
    var marker_<?php echo $gauging["Gauging"]["id"]; ?> = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: MyMap.map,
            title: '<?php echo $gauging["Gauging"]["identification"]; ?>',
            position: randLatLng,
            draggable: false, 
            clickable: true, 
            icon: '/img/markers/yellow_Marker.png',
            myId: 'gp_<?php echo $gauging["Gauging"]["id"]; ?>'
        });
    myMap.markers.push(marker_<?php echo $gauging["Gauging"]["id"]; ?>);

// loop ends here .......

var markerYellowCluster = new MarkerClusterer(myMap, yellowMarkers);
```

... and this code creates all of the markers fine, but it does not add them into clusterer.

Can you give me some suggestions how I can fix this?

Tnx in adv!

**UPDATE:** maybe this can help - alert(yellowMarkers); shows alert window, with:

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

Comment: can you post the output that the php creates? you don't have to post the whole list of markers just a single one

Comment: with php i only add marker properties, and it works fine. problem is that i can not group created markers into marker clusterer. which part of php code you think can help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I've done this before, my code looked like this:

```
var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
            zoomOnClick: true,
            averageCenter: true
        });
```

What is `yellowMarkers`?  Shouldn't that be myMap.markers?

Comment: Variable yellowMarkers in my case is variable markers in yours. Like variable myMap in mine and map in yours. There must be some small mistake on my side... Can you check Update part of my question?

Comment: If the code you pasted is the code you're using, then duncan's correct in saying that yellowMarkers doesn't seem like the correct collection to use. You've obviously populated it somewhere in your code, but the code you posted doesn't show where. It shows you populating myMap.markers. So try var markerYellowCluster = new MarkerClusterer(myMap, myMap.markers);

Comment: Also, at one point you refer to MyMap.map, and then you refer to myMap.markers. Javascript is case-sensitive. And you pass just myMap to the marker clusterer. Do you mean to pass myMap.map?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with some of the comments above about what your variables are named, but I wanted to add another option here.

You can initialize the markerclusterer before you start adding any markers:

```
var markerYellowCluster = new MarkerClusterer(myMap);
```

Then instead of calling:

```
myMap.markers.push(marker_<?php echo $gauging["Gauging"]["id"]; ?>);
```

You can simply call the "addMarker" method on the markerclusterer object itself and it will both add the marker to the map as well as the marker clusterer:

```
markerYellowCluster.addMarker(marker_<?php echo $gauging["Gauging"]["id"]; ?>);
```